# Core data add new column without rebuild indexing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I have a very huge core data table (around 400k+ record inside), I create a new model version and add a column inside, after that I launch the app and I took me 10 minutes+ to complete whole core data migration activity.

It seem like Xcode auto rebuild the indexing after I add a new column.

I want to add a new column without rebuild the indexing, how to do that?

> CoreData: sql: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS
>   Z_XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject_messageStatus CoreData:
>   sql: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS
>   Z_XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject_messageStatus CoreData:
>   sql: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS
>   Z_XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject_messageType CoreData:
>   sql: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS
>   Z_XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject_messageType CoreData:
>   sql: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS
>   Z_XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject_outgoing CoreData: sql:
>   DROP INDEX IF EXISTS
>   Z_XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject_outgoing
>
> CoreData: sql: CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS
>   Z_XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject_messageStatus ON
>   ZXMPPMESSAGEARCHIVING_MESSAGE_COREDATAOBJECT (ZMESSAGESTATUS COLLATE
>   BINARY ASC) CoreData: sql: CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS
>   Z_XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject_messageType ON
>   ZXMPPMESSAGEARCHIVING_MESSAGE_COREDATAOBJECT (ZMESSAGETYPE COLLATE
>   BINARY ASC) CoreData: sql: CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS
>   Z_XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject_outgoing ON
>   ZXMPPMESSAGEARCHIVING_MESSAGE_COREDATAOBJECT (ZOUTGOING COLLATE BINARY
>   ASC)

Thanks.

Comment: How are you implementing the migration?

Comment: Hi, all the migration is auto handle by Xcode.

Editor > Add Model Version > Done
Under XcdatamodelId > Model Version > Current version.
Under entity > Add new attributes.

Run the app and auto execute the migration.

Comment: Have you enabled “lightweight migration” in your Xcode project?